# Getting Microsoft PlayReady server to output to Windows Media DRM 10 PD (Portable Devices)

Tags: streaming, drm, windows-media-server

Is it possible to get Microsoft PlayReady Server to output DRM'd streams that are playable by Windows Media DRM 10-PD compatible devices?

If so, where could I find any relevant documentation?

Comment: Isn't that a ServerFault question?

Comment: Perhaps? How does moving it there work, or should I just reopen it on ServerFault as well?

Comment: I think you'd need a moderator, or close (off topic) votes.

Comment: 'This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed' :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You need to use so-called "cocktail licenses" and encrypt ASF (i.e. WMV) streams. The relevant documentation is part of the PlayReady Server documentation set, which unfortunately requires you to be a PlayReady Server licensee from Microsoft ([you can become a licensee here](https://wmlicense.smdisp.net/licenserequest-04/licenserequest.aspx), but it does cost quite a bit of money).

Answer (score 1):

PlayReady server will only deliver licenses to PlayReady clients. unfortunately any of the PD clients will not be able to talk to PlayReady Server.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple aspects to consider here. I am not sure which one exactly the question is about, so I will cover all of them. First, some background information.

There are two types of DRM-protected WMV files:

1. WMV files protected with Windows Media DRM
2. WMV files protected with PlayReady

There are also two types of media players:

1. Using the Windows Media DRM engine
2. Using the Playready engine

And finally, there are also two types of license servers:

1. Windows Media DRM
2. PlayReady.

The compatibility relationships between these are the following:

- **Windows Media DRM files** can be played in **both types of media player**.
- **PlayReady files** can be played only in media players using the **PlayReady engine**.
- What sort of licensing server you need depends on the media player, not the file.
- **Windows Media DRM licensing servers** can only create licenses for **Windows Media DRM players**.
- **PlayReady licensing servers** can only create licenses for media players using the **PlayReady engine**.

*Note: I am not familiar with the differences between the different types of Windows Media DRM licenses (Portable VS Network), so there might be additional considerations*